# How to store command output to variable which has asterisk(*)?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying capture command output to a variable but asterisk(*) characters automatically gets converted into directory files.

Command I want to run

```
secrets=$(vault read kv/data/secrets)
```

**Expression to recreate the scenario**

```
cronExpression=$(echo "33 * * *") && echo $cronExpression
```

**Expected**

```
cronExpression="33 * * *"
```

**Actual**

```
33 LICENSE README.md test.json LICENSE README.md test.json LICENSE README.md test.json
```

I have `LICENSE README.md test.json` files in a folder where I am trying to execute this command so each `*` gets converted into list files in the same directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
cronExpression="$(echo "33 * * *")" && echo "$cronExpression"
33 * * *
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added `GLOBIGNORE=*` to fix the issue.

Comment: There's no need of this variable with proper quoting

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam That breaks places where you want wildcard expansion to work, and doesn't avoid problems with word splitting. Double-quoting variable references *works*.

Comment: Consider accepting answer if it fits your needs